# PageSpeed insight results are not being updated even after modifying the files

Tags: .htaccess, caching, http-headers, pagespeed, google-pagespeed

I have the following code in my .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On

ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 year"
</IfModule>
```

This means that `jpg` and `jpeg` images should have a cache expiration date of 1 year. The response headers in Chrome's DevTools Console reflect that.

```
content-type:image/jpeg
date:Mon, 07 Nov 2016 04:05:46 GMT
expires:Tue, 07 Nov 2017 04:05:46 GMT
last-modified:Sun, 06 Nov 2016 18:40:41 GMT
```

However, on PageSpeed insights, the recommendations show that the cache is only valid for 5 hours and I should increase that time. Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the newer `Cache-Control` header:

```
Cache-Control: max-age=<some-time-in-seconds>, public
```

The old HTTP/1 `Expires` header is imprecise and causes problems when intermediate caches are involved.

Google PageSpeed probably assumes that it will not be respected by browsers. In that case the browser reverts to so called **heuristic caching** where the expiration is typically calculated as a fraction (e.g. 20%) of the difference between the `Last-Modified` date and now - which would yield a value similar to the one you saw.